# Is there any valid reason why Oracle has not updated their Operator Precedence Table to include the lambda operator?

Tags: java, oracle, lambda, java-8

Java 8 was released with Lambda expressions as a new language feature on March, 2014. I would think that it would be important to also update their Operator Precedence Table.

Here is the link to the table from Oracle: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: Perhaps because the lambda *operator* is not an **operator**, it is sort of syntactic sugar.

Comment: The [lambda **expression**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) is implemented by an abstract class; `->` isn't an operator (it just looks like one).

Comment: "Lambda operator" does not exist.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on an incorrect assumption that "lambda operator" exists.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Mistaking the arrow syntax (`->`) for an operator isn't the worst assumption I've ever seen made. There's probably a duplicate though. Found "one". Dropping Mjölnir on it.

Comment: Thanks guys, I did make the mistake of assuming that lambda was an operator rather than an expression. I should have read more on lambda expressions rather than posting this.